# Diable the button , enable button after another button clock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want that until the `Copy List To Below` get clicked I want to disable to `Save` button.

Currently this is the `Copy List To Below` button

```html
<button type="button" className={classes["copy-btn"] + " btn-cancel mt-3"} onClick={(event) => this.copyData(event)}>Copy List To Below {_.size(this.state.protestList) > 1 ? _.size(this.state.protestList) + " Groups" : 'Group'} </button>
```

And this is my `Save` button

```html
     <button type="submit" className={classes["save-btn"] + " btn-save"} onClick={(event) => this.saveData(event)}>Save</button>
```

And below is the respected functions

```
    saveDate = (event, data) => {
        if(event) {
            //Do something
        }
        else {
            //Return Error
        }
    }

    copyData = (event, data) => {
            if(event) {
                //Do something
            }
            else {
                //Return Error
            }
        }
```

As I said only if Copy is done then only save button should be able get clicked

Answer (score 1):

Give two ids and add click event and toggle button disable property like this. Make it simple. Your buttons has unnecessary attributes, please remove those.

**CORE JAVASCRIPT**

```
<button type="button" id="coptBtn" class ="btn-cancel mt-3" >Copy List To Below</button>
<button id="saveBtn" type="submit" class="" >Save</button>

var coptBtn  = document.getElementById('coptBtn');
var saveBtn  = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
saveBtn.disabled = true;
coptBtn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    saveBtn.disabled = false;
 });
```

**REACT JS**

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {isDisable: false}
  }, 
  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({isDisable: true})
  },
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} >Copy List To Below</button>
      <button type="button" disabled={!this.state.isDisable}>Save</button>
   </div>
  } 
});
```

Comment: `TypeError: saveBtn is null` this error placing it in render()

Comment: did you add `id` to `SAVE` button?

Comment: YES I ADDED `id` to Save

Comment: It is a tested answer. And should work. Please share some of you code else check thoroughly. And make sure you have kept id unique else give a unique id.

Comment: I an placing under `render()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
copyData() {
    //your existing code
    this.setState({copied: true})
        }

    <button type="submit" disable={!this.state.copied} className={classes["save-btn"] + " btn-save"} onClick={(event) => this.saveData(event)}>Save</button>
```